# Sorted SAS tables not merging

Tags: sas

I am trying to do a simple merge and getting an error that "BY variables are not properly sorted on data set WORK.GMBY1"

They are sorted, I have sorted them and checked manually that they are sorted.

Variables are of the same size and format in each table.

A proc SQL join does not work either.

Any clues on what could be the problem here?

Thanks.

```
proc sort data=total_channels (where=(orders ne . and website_country='UK')) out=sorted_channels; 
by website_country year_order month_order channel;
run;

proc sort data=gmby out=gmby1;
by website_country year_order month_order channel;
where website_country='UK';
run;

data gmby_merge;
merge sorted_channels gmby1;
by website_country year_order month_order channel;
run;
```

LOG

```
ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set WORK.GMBY1.
website_country=UK year_order=2012 month_order=9 orders=. bookings=. gm=. channel=DisplayRetargeting order_count=3
fo_gm_euro=22.605769157 yr1_gm_euro=67.88001442 cum_yr2=90.972795325 cum_yr3=108.83075505 cum_yr4=124.35002072 cum_yr5=138.15287302
fiscal_year=2013 fiscal_quarter=1 FIRST.website_country=0 LAST.website_country=0 FIRST.year_order=0 LAST.year_order=0
FIRST.month_order=0 LAST.month_order=0 FIRST.channel=1 LAST.channel=1 _ERROR_=1 _N_=40
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```

Comment: Post the log from the above code

Comment: What do you mean an SQL join doesn't work either?  There's no `sort` requirements for a join, so it makes me think something else is causing the issue.

Comment: I suspect that you are wrong, and they do have different lengths or formats.  I can count a number of times this has happened with colleagues, and it always turns out the lengths or formats are different.  Either that or there's an error in the PROC SORT that they're not looking at.

Comment: Yes, please show full log from both the sort steps and the merge step.  I agree with Joe, probably there was an error in the sort step.  If the BY variables were different lengths, you should get a warning about possible unexpected results due to different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually due to "channel" containing a capitalised variable.

I had "DRTV" and "Direct Type-In" and the former was being sorted before the latter, since SAS sorts capitals ahead of lowercase hence the join fail. I lowercased the DRTV.

I had no idea that caps mattered! Good to know.

Thanks all.